# Routing traffic through a host connected to the VPN gateway

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn

I have a VPN set up where multiple subnets are used. I have three VPN services, let's say A - `192.168.1.0/24`, B - `192.168.2.0/24` and C - `192.168.3.0/24`. I would like to have specific traffic from a host in subnet C through a host in subnet A. In effect

```
(CLIENT) 192.168.3.12 ---->  VPN GATEWAY ---> (SERVER) 192.168.1.49 ---> INTERNET
```

I have set up port forwarding on the VPN gateway and on the SERVER machines with

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I have set up traffic between subnets on the VPN gateway using

```
 iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o tun3 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A FORWARD -i tun3 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
```

I have set up routes on the SERVER machine

```
ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 dev tun0
```

and on the CLIENT machine

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev tun0
```

At this point I can connect from the CLIENT to the SERVER using SSH, so I consider this part solved. However, as soon as I try to add a route that goes through the SERVER machine, e.g.

```
ip route add 1.1.1.1 via 192.168.1.49
```

I am no longer able to ping 1.1.1.1 . I can see that on the VPN gateway the packets in the FORWARD table are being dropped at a rate that corresponds to my ping requests, but not sure what I am doing wrong.

How can I debug this connection issue when trying to route traffic through a host behind the VPN gateway?